# WindowManager.addView() crashes

Tags: android, sdk

Here is my code :

```
protected window_fly (Context context) {

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams (
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT ) ;

    params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.BOTTOM ;

    LayoutInflater layOutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)  ;
    View in_view = layOutInflater.inflate(R.layout.in_layout, null) ;
    Toast.makeText(context, "daemon born", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() ; 
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(context.WINDOW_SERVICE); 
    //wm.addView(in_view, params);
}
```

all in Service context. window_fly is the constructor. If I uncomment wm.addView() and run it, app will fall. Please, tell me possible reasons of it. Sorry for poor English.

Comment: whats the error (check logcat for the crash stacktrace)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added to Manifest line with description of permissions for SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```